# DB2 iSeries v6.1 vs Linux v9.7 functionality on xmltable, xml doc

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Techies--
I'm getting sql0204 XML in *LIBL type *SQLUDT not found on an i db2 6.1 install when I try to deploy a stored proc I know works on Linux v9.7. The reason I am attempting to get this to work is because I really need to pass a table (or array) variable. I couldn't find a way to send a multi-dim array to a sproc on the 6.1 v of i, so I thought I'd try getting around that with an xml doc. But that failed too... Does anyone have any advice for me on how to solve this issue?

Here's the sproc that works on v9.7,Linux:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE HCMDEV.EMP_MULTIPLE_XML (IN DOC XML)
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  READS SQL DATA
  LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC EMP_MULTIPLE_XML

  P1: BEGIN

  DECLARE CSR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT emp.EMPID,
           emp.FIRSTNAME,
           emp.LASTNAME,
           emp.DIVISION,
           emp.DISTRICT,
           emp.LOCATION,
           emp.OPERATIONALAREA,
           emp.TERMDATE,
           emp.REHIREDATE,
           emp.HIREDATE,
           emp.ADDRESSLINE1,
           emp.ADDRESSLINE2,
           emp.CITY,
           emp.STATE,
           emp.ZIPCODE,
           emp.TELEPHONE1,
           emp.POSITIONCODE,
           emp.POSITIONTITLE,
           emp.HIRECODE
        FROM HCMDEV.EMPLOYEE emp
         WHERE EMP.EMPID IN
          (SELECT X.EMPID
           FROM XMLTABLE('$d/EMPLOYEE/EMPID' PASSING DOC AS "d" COLUMNS EMPID CHAR(9) PATH '.') AS X);

  OPEN CSR1;
  END P1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those following this thread, xmltable is NOT available until V7R1. The workaround is to create a stored proc that accepts as the IN paramater a CLOB datatype. In my case, I pass a long string with commas to separate the values for the empid. That works just fine.
Here's a sampling:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE HCMDEV.EMP_MULT (IN emp_array CLOB(2M))
 DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
 READS SQL DATA
 LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC EMP_MULT
 P1: BEGIN
-- #######################################################################
-- # Returns specific employees based on incoming clob array
-- #######################################################################


DECLARE v_dyn varchar(10000);
DECLARE v_sql varchar(10000);

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR v_dyn;

SET v_sql = 
  'SELECT
     emp.EMPID,
     emp.FIRSTNAME,
     emp.LASTNAME
     FROM HCMDEV.EMPLOYEE emp
      WHERE emp.EMPID IN (' || emp_array || ')';

   PREPARE v_dyn FROM v_sql;

   OPEN cursor1;
```

END P1